# Insert data from a table into another table with resulsets

Tags: java, sql-server

I need to migrate some table's data into another table in the same database;

for example table1:

```
PersonID    LastName    FirstName   Address  City
1            Foo          Bar        xxx     boh
2            Foo          Bar        xxx     boh
3            Foo          Bar        xxx     boh
```

and table2

```
 PersonID   field2  field3  field4   field5
 1          boh     xxx     Foo      Bar
 2          boh     xxx     Foo      Bar
 3          boh     xxx     Foo      Bar
```

I've tried with this sample code:

```
ResultSet table1 = s.executeQuery("Select * from table1");
ResultSet table2 = s.executeQuery("Select * from table2");
 
while(table1.next()) {
     table2.insertRow();
}
```

But with just that instruction I got "The result set is closed." error.
Can I insert in table2 the same amount of rows of table1?
Then I tought about adding information by reading informations from table1 and adding them to table2 with the resultset updateRow method.

EDIT: Table2 in the beginning should be empty, with just the structure created.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use select into statement https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_select_into.asp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've resolved by changing the type of the resultset in resultset.CONCUR_UPDATABLE, and adding this in the while:

```
while(table1.next()) {
    table2.moveToInsertRow();
    tabella2.updateString("PersonID", table1.getString("PersonID"));
    table2.insertRow();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming in Table1 you have PersonId = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 and in Table2 you have only PersonId = 1, 2 only, if you wish to copy PersonId = 3, 4, 5 from Table1 to Table2, you can achieve this by this query:

```
INSERT INTO Table2
SELECT t1.PersonId, t1.LastName, t1.FirstName, t1.Address, t1.City
FROM Table1 t1
LEFT JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.PersonId = t2.PersonId
WHERE t2.PersonId IS NULL;
```

If you wish to get this done from the application, you can just execute it like this:

```
s.executeQuery(<query>); // <query> is the query I mentioned above.
```